# How to make it possible to add a LWUIT Form inside a LWUIT Form?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I tried to add a LWUIT `Form` into another LWUIT `Form` but I received an internal error in runtime :

```
Installing suite from: http://127.0.0.1:1975/SmartPhoneBanking.jad
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A form cannot be added to a container
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.insertComponentAt(), bci=50
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.addComponent(), bci=19
 - com.sun.lwuit.Form.addComponent(), bci=5
 - view.test.<init>(), bci=63
 - view.MenuPrincipalForm.actionPerformed(), bci=178
 - com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(), bci=19
 - com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(), bci=89
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.fireActionEvent(), bci=70
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.released(), bci=17
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.pointerReleased(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.Form.pointerReleased(), bci=93
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.pointerReleased(), bci=7
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.handleEvent(), bci=125
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.edtLoopImpl(), bci=115
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.mainEDTLoop(), bci=198
 - com.sun.lwuit.RunnableWrapper.run(), bci=242
 - java.lang.Thread.run(), bci=11
Process exited with exit code 0
```

Although a LWUIT `Form` is a LWUIT `Component` ! So the addComponent should work with a LWUIT `Form` !

So how to make it possible ?

codes :

```
public class test extends Form
{
   private Button b = new Button("xxx");
   public test(String t)
   {
      super(t);
      addComponent(b);
   }
}
```

In another `Form` :

```
...
private Form xxx = new test("xxx");
...
addComponent(xxx);
...
```

Comment: post your code. Because its possible to add the one `Form` to another `Form`. There is no issue.

Comment: I included the codes in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a form to a container, says it right in the exception when you add xxx to wherever it is you are adding it to.

Use `xxx.show()` do not add it to anything.

Comment: But I want to make a `transition` about the Button contained in it. So that's why I want to add the Form. So if calling `show()` then the new Form will occupy all of the area of the already shown form ! But I want just an area to be occupied !

Comment: addComponent will not form a transition, only replace. Regardless of that, what is the behavior you expect with adding a form into a place of a button? Do you want the entire title and everything to appear where the button is?

Comment: I want the Button to have a Transition appearance when adding it into a Form.

Comment: You are adding the form to the container not the button to the form which is wrong regardless of what you are trying to do. To do a simple animation just use replace() which accepts a transition. In LWUIT 1.5 you can also animate the layout so a button will "fly in" see the LWUITDemo 1.5's animations demo for samples of that.